# How do I create a specific process using fork()?

Tags: c

I have multiple processes; a `controller` and a `person`. The `controller` needs to spawn off multiple `person` processes based on user inputted value.

How using `fork()` do I specify to create a `person` process?

```
pid_t child = fork(); // How do I make this a `person`?
```

From what I understand, `fork()` just makes a copy of the current process. What am I missing?

Comment: If the `person` processes are a different executable from the initial (`controller`) process, then you need to `exec*()` after the `fork()` to run the appropriate other executable.  If the `person` processes simply run a different function in the same executable, then after the `fork()` returns as a child, the child can arrange to execute the `person` code (function) while the controller continues to execute the controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fork indeed makes a copy of the current process. Once this is done, you can use `execve()` in order to execute your new process.

Answer (score 2):

`fork` indeed copies the current process, once you are in the new copy, you should execute the other program using one of the [`exec`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) functions family.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing is that `fork()` returns information that can be used to determine whether you are now running in the original process or the child process. Follow the `fork()` call with a test for that, and if you're in the child start running the child's logic.

See some of the answers under **Related** at right.